# Select year from object type field using python and streamlit

Tags: python, pandas, date, streamlit

I have a dataframe that includes a  column "birthdate" but its of type **object**  like this `1984-11-15` format y%-%M-%d.
I want to convert it to date and just extract the year with **no duplication**  in order to filter the dataframe based on the year.

I am using the multiselect option in order to allow the user to filter the dataframe choosing multiple options, but when i try to convert the column type the system crash and display the below error.

**StreamlitAPIException** : Every Multiselect default value must exist in options

Traceback:

```
File "f:\AIenv\streamlit\TEC_APPS\fit_in_out_leb.py", line 762, in <module>
    main()File "f:\AIenv\streamlit\TEC_APPS\fit_in_out_leb.py", line 366, in main
    db_stb =  st.sidebar.multiselect("Select  date of birth ",list(query_bd),default = query_bd)
```

what this error mean and how to fix it ?

code:

```
df['birthdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['birthdate'])
query_bd = df.birthdate.unique()
db_stb =  st.sidebar.multiselect("Select  date of birth ",list(query_bd),default = query_bd)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new column for year, this column is used to generate the unique options and select a frame based on year.

```py
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

d = {
    'birthdate': ['2022-01-01', '2021-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2019-01-01', '2019-02-05']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['birthdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['birthdate'])
df['year'] = df['birthdate'].dt.year

query_bd = df.year.unique()
db_stb =  st.sidebar.multiselect("Select  date of birth ", query_bd, default=query_bd)

selected = df.loc[df['year'].isin(db_stb)]
st.write(selected['birthdate'].dt.date)
```

##### Output

[image]

Comment: if i try your answer it crash and display :
`"Every Multiselect default value must exist in options"
streamlit.errors.StreamlitAPIException: Every Multiselect default value must exist in options`

But if i convert the `query_bd ` into a list it works but the type becomes float and the result is **2020.0**,**2022.0**

Comment: I use streamlit==1.3.1 and streamlit==1.6.0 on windows 10 and both works. According to the doc at https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.multiselect the options can take different types.